# What to check from the owner whether a cheese is halal or not?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Assalamu walaikum

I saw this [cheese product](https://www.kraftrecipes.com/product/00021000055166/kraft-mozzarella-finely-shredded-natural-cheese-8-oz-pouch?categoryid=10060) made by kraft and I wanted to know whether it is halal or not.

[image]

So I sent an email to Kraft company asking about whether this is halal or made from any animal enzymes or not? They responded back with this:

> "Thanks for your interest in KRAFT Mozzarella cheese. None of our
>   mozzarella products contain animal-based enzymes. I hope you continue
>   to enjoy our products."

So should I ask any follow up question? If yes, then what should I ask them because I don't know what else I should check with them before I decide to eat this cheese?

And if not then is this halal to eat?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** @AsanRamzan Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for answering questions. If you want to answer the question, use the "Post Your Answer" field below so it can be properly peer-reviewed.

Comment: @goldPseudo I was sure I read some were if you had a very short ansewer that you should give it as a comments, but I must have been mistaken, anyway the person contacted me and knows what I said. Next time I will Post even short answers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to check these:

- whether the milk, from which the cheese is made, is of a permissible animal
- whether the [rennet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennet) used to make the cheese is from a permissible animal
- whether that animal (source of rennet) was slaughtered according to Islamic requirements. There is difference of opinion on this.
- if any other ingredients are added for flavoring etc., whether they are halal

Cheese that claims to be vegetarian or kosher should be halal.